# How can I use an alternative kubeconfig file?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubeconfig

By default, `kubectl` configuration is located at `~/.kube/config`. Is it possible to specify the kubeconfig file explicitly when using the `kubectl` command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`kubectl` can use the `KUBECONFIG` in three different ways:

1. Using the `KUBECONFIG` present in `~/.kube/config` if nothing is specified in `kubectl` command.
2. Using the `KUBECONFIG` defined by using the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable if nothing is specified in `kubectl` command.
3. Passing the `KUBECONFIG` as part of the `kubectl` command using the `--kubeconfig` flag as:

   ```
   kubectl --kubeconfig=<KUBECONFIG_PATH>
   ```

Further, the order of precedence is as follows:

1. Use the `KUBECONFIG` if explicitly passed in the `kubectl` command
2. Use the `KUBECONFIG` from the environment variable if `--kubeconfig` flag is not specified but the environment variable is set.
3. Use the `KUBECONFIG` from `~/.kube/config` if both `--kubeconfig` and `KUBECONFIG` are not specified.

Answer (score 3):

Use `KUBECONFIG` env for using custom kubeconfig file with `kubectl`:

```sh
$ export KUBECONFIG=/path/to/config
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can specify like this

```
kubectl config --kubeconfig=your_kubeconfi_file_path <YOUR_OPERATION>
```